# Entity Framework Добавление/Удаление из таблицы

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Доброго всем времени суток. Начал работу с Entity Framework и возникла пара вопросов:
1)Если добавляю несколько записей в таблицу, то они очень сильно путаются, хотя вроде задан ID как primary key.
2)От этой проблемы может помочь избавиться `db.SaveChanges();` после каждой операции `db.Add();` ,но я чувствую, что при больших объемах это создаст большие проблемы с производительностью. Как будет лучше сделать?
3)Как можно очистить таблицу так, чтобы значение ID(primary key) вновь стало 1?
Код:

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Int32 Age { get; set; }
    }
```

```
class ApplicationContext:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext()
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=AppDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
```

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Clear();
           Create();
        }
        public static void Create()
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    User x = new User { Name="Name"+i.ToString(),Age=i };
                    db.Add(x);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        public static void Clear()
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                db.Users.RemoveRange(db.Users);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Айдишники не для человека, они для машины. Забудьте про них. Вам должно быть безразлично, чему равен ID: 1, 20 или 100500. Занимайтесь творчеством, а не выравниванием циферок.

Comment: Вы упоминаете о больших объёмах. Насколько больших? Возможно, стоит рассмотреть переход на другую ORM вместо унылого EF. Например, [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db#bulk-copy). Или хотя бы взять расширение [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Добавляйте не по одному объекту, а сразу пачкой [как тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addrange?view=efcore-5.0). ID хранится на стороне БД, сбросить его можно командой [DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) в случае SQL Server. Похожие механизмы есть у других СУБД: [MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923114/how-to-reset-auto-increment-in-mysql), [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342440/reset-auto-increment-counter-in-postgres). Нужно будет написать SQL запрос и вызывать через метод [Database.ExecuteSqlCommand](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0).

Comment: У автора вопрос по EF, без указания конкретной СУБД. Соответственно, вендор-специфичные команды наподобие DBCC могут быть недоступны.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Точно, автоматом думаю про SQL Server. Дополнил.